# Retrieve image alternative text in wordpress and alpine js

Tags: wordpress, alpine.js

I'm trying to retrieve the alt text of an image related to a post inserted in the WordPress backend using Alpine.js.

I've attempted to access the alt text through both post.alt and post.image.alt, but unfortunately, neither approach seems to work.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

html

```
    <template x-for="(post, index) in posts">
        <div class="border-t even:md:border-r p-8">
            <div :class="{ 'md:flex md:flex-col-reverse': index % 2 !== 0 }">
                <a :href="post.link.url" class="image-link group">
                    <img
                         :alt="post.image.alt"
                         :src="post.image"
                         class="block rounded-lg transform w-full mb-8 overflow-hidden transition           
      group-hover:scale-95"
                     :class="{ 'md:mb-0': index % 2 !== 0 }"
                    />
               </a>
            </div>
         </div> 
     </template>
```

I'm looking for assistance in correctly accessing the alt text of the image associated with each post in the posts array. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: *posts* where comes from?

Comment: And you can try also `console.log(posts[0])`  or  `console.log(posts[0].image)` to see how it is composed